# loading problem in android

Tags: android

I have develop one app in which **four box question** are there. all question are set as `swf` animated file. there are three activity

***First :>*** splash screen
***Second :>*** main screen
***Third :>*** last screen

Now in main screen stay question part.
**Problem : >** when i test on device display splash screen and after comming main screen but main screen take approx five minute to load and something black screen display at this time after five minute wait it will display properly. so i suffering this delay problem can you explain why this is raise. and how to solve or reduce time?

my all code are stay in `onCreate();` method

Comment: can you post your code please ?

Comment: are you loading anything from a database or something? if it's just some gui elements then it should be pretty instant even on slower devices. post some code also so that people can offer suggestions on speeding up your loading.

Comment: Show us your main activity code. It will be helpful to also show your splash screen activity.

Comment: @kevin i havent use any db operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you seeing your UI after completing onCreate method.So you are not seeing your UI.To overcome this you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class for long running operation.Use doInBackground method for the processing of data and to update UI,you can use onProgressUpdate method